# OSM Nominatim search strange behaviour

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have ran into some troubles using Open Street Map Nominatim search API. I am trying to search and geocode addresses, but for some queries, the results are quite strange.

For example, when I use query:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&countrycodes=cz&limit=10&accept-language=cz&addressdetails=1&q=Jihlava
```

I get expected results - city Jihlava.

But when I use queries like (**only part of name**):

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&countrycodes=cz&limit=10&accept-language=cz&addressdetails=1&q=Jihl
```

or

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&countrycodes=cz&limit=10&accept-language=cz&addressdetails=1&q=Jihla
```

or

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&countrycodes=cz&limit=10&accept-language=cz&addressdetails=1&q=Jihlav
```

**I get empty result list.**

**Is there anything wrong with my query?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's expected behavior, for now. Nominatim has no auto-correction feature yet. Thus only partly matching queries aren't always handled correctly.

If you need auto-correction then please see if one of the other [search engines for OSM](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) fits your needs.